# How to create a scipy matrix that is MxN where, M and N are decided by the user and the elements are fed one after the other?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

I want to create a 2-d matrix of coordinates.  I want the use to be able to decide the number of rows and columns, and the elements of the matrix when the program is run.  I know how to do this using arrays which I have done here:

```
F = int(raw_input("Enter expected number of frames: "))
P = int(raw_input("Enter expected points to track object: "))
W = []
for i in xrange (2*F):
 W.append([])
 print "frame number", (i+1)
 for j in xrange (P):
  W[i].append(int(raw_input("Enter the next coordinate: ")))
print W
```

My question is how do I do the same using the matrix functions in scipy (or numpy).  I want to do this so I can easily perform inverses and calculate SVD etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
import numpy as np

F = int(raw_input("Enter expected number of frames: "))
P = int(raw_input("Enter expected points to track object: "))
W = np.zeros(shape = (2*F, P))


for i in xrange (2*F):
  for j in xrange (P):
    print "Frame: ", (i+1), "Point: ", (j+1)
    W[i][j] = (int(raw_input("Enter the next coordinate: ")))
print W
```

Comment: Note that here using the zeros function from numpy makes all the element 0 that when initialized.  There is an alternate function in numpy that you can use that does NOT do this (if you so desire).

Comment: You should get used to indexing numpy arrays as `W[i, j]` instead of `W[i][j]`.

Comment: How does using [i,j] differ from [i][j]?

Comment: I believe that using `W[i][j]` is more limited when using advanced slicing, for example, if you want to use boolean slicing.    See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: When you use `W[i][j]` you are creating a view `W[i]` of your array, then extracting the `j`-th element from that view before discarding the view. If you do `W[i, j]` no intermediate view is created, everything happens under the hood in numpy's C code. So it is faster.